Implications of having access to the Busy Beaver oracle
Apologies if I'm asking a naïve question as I've only recently learned about the concept.
What would be the practical implications  (if any) of having access to a magical black box providing the values of $\Sigma(n)$?
Of course, this would readily imply access to the "answers" to long-standing open problems in math, but without proofs those probably wouldn't be particularly influential. So could we make any use at all of such an oracle?
A follow-up question: Is there any relation between the values of $\Sigma(n)$ for different $n$ which could allow one to check whether the oracle is providing self-consistent outputs?

Even if we had this oracle and a turing machine with a fixed amount of states can actually check all cases of an open problem (I am not sure anymore about this since I noticed a talk about this claim) , the practical value would be very small since a useful machine will have at least $10$ states and recently it has been proven that $bb(6)>10\uparrow \uparrow 15$ , so even the humble $6$-state machines can have running times beyond astronomical.

We only know that $bb(n)$ grows asymptotically faster than any computable function and that it is strictly increasing. So, an independent verification of this oracle will only work upto $5$ states.

This oracle would enable us to solve the halting problem , so in principal , it would be a very powerful tool.

It's uncomputable to check whether a number is indeed the correct BB number or not. Otherwise the halting problem is then solvable.

It would be completely impractical to do anything with such an oracle (including checking whether it makes sense) because the busy beaver numbers are so enormous, but in theory, we would be able to solve the halting problem for Turing machines (there would be a new kind of halting problem that is undecidable in this new world). In particular, we would be able to prove ZFC's consistency one way or the other, along with every math problem that can be encoded in a Turing machine.
There is a Wiki link on this very topic if you want more information: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercomputation
